# Calling a function crashes when the stack pointer is changed with inline assembly

Tags: stack, rust, inline-assembly

I have written some code that changes the current stack used by modifying the stack pointer in inline assembly. Although I can call functions and create local variables, calls to `println!` and some functions from `std::rt` result in the application terminating abnormally with signal 4 (illegal instruction) in [the playpen](http://is.gd/nirKJm). How should I improve the code to prevent crashes?

```rust
#![feature(asm, box_syntax)]

#[allow(unused_assignments)]
#[inline(always)]
unsafe fn get_sp() -> usize {
    let mut result = 0usize;
    asm!("
        movq %rsp, $0
        "
        :"=r"(result):::"volatile"
    );
    result
}

#[inline(always)]
unsafe fn set_sp(value: usize) {
    asm!("
        movq $0, %rsp
        "
        ::"r"(value)::"volatile"
    );
}

#[inline(never)]
unsafe fn foo() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut stack = box [0usize; 500];
        let len = stack.len();
        stack[len-1] = get_sp();
        set_sp(std::mem::transmute(stack.as_ptr().offset((len as isize)-1)));
        foo();
        asm!("
            movq (%rsp), %rsp
            "
            ::::"volatile"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why do to manipulate the stack in this way, and why do you think anything should continue to work afterwards?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer what I'm asking. It's a learning exercise. Everything *should* work as before; the only thing that should fail is accessing local variables defined before the stack changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging the program with rust-lldb on x86_64 on OS X yields 300K stack traces, repeating these lines over and over:

```
frame #299995: 0x00000001000063c4 a`rt::util::report_overflow::he556d9d2b8eebb88VbI + 36
frame #299996: 0x0000000100006395 a`rust_stack_exhausted + 37
frame #299997: 0x000000010000157f a`__morestack + 13
```

`morestack` is assembly for each platform, like [`i386`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a81ce5f991148b3c701c6b4276cdcafe366cd8f4/src/rt/arch/i386/morestack.S) and [`x86_64`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a81ce5f991148b3c701c6b4276cdcafe366cd8f4/src/rt/arch/x86_64/morestack.S) — the i386 variant has more description that I think you will want to read carefully. This piece stuck out to me:

> Each Rust function contains an LLVM-generated prologue that compares the stack space required for the current function to the space remaining in the current stack segment, maintained in a platform-specific TLS slot.

Here's the first instructions of the `foo` method:

```
a`foo::h5f80496ac1ee3d43zaa:
   0x1000013e0:  cmpq   %gs:0x330, %rsp
   0x1000013e9:  ja     0x100001405               ; foo::h5f80496ac1ee3d43zaa + 37
   0x1000013eb:  movabsq $0x48, %r10
   0x1000013f5:  movabsq $0x0, %r11
-> 0x1000013ff:  callq  0x100001572               ; __morestack
```

As you can see, I am about to call into `__morestack`, so the comparison check failed.

I believe that this indicates that **you cannot manipulate the stack pointer** and attempt to call any Rust functions.

As a side note, let's look at your `get_sp` assembly:

```
movq %rsp, $0
```

Doing a check check for [the semantics of `movq`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_201.html):

> Copies a quadword from the source operand (second operand) to the destination operand (first operand).

That seems to indicate that your assembly is *backwards*, in addition to all the other problems.

Comment: Thanks for finding out where the program is crashing! I tried debugging the executable using visual studio but could not understand what was happening. Would it be possible to modify `%gs:0x330`?

Comment: @James I honestly don't know, but my guess would be "not without changing the Rust compiler". The comment from the source seems to indicate that this is a core part of the code generation.